# Building a Bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha 6 navbar with Angular 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap for Bootstrap 4 components, but neither ngx-bootstrap nor ng-boostrap have a navbar component.  The [github issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/540) suggests using the ngx-bootstrap collapse module, but I've struggled to get it working, especially with dropdown links.

For example, how should I go about enabling the dropdown links and collapse function on this navbar using Angular 4?  The dropdown link works, but the dropdown is attached to the navbar, not the body.

```
<div class="navbar-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xl navbar-light bg-faded">
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">My App</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/table" routerLinkActive="active">AR Table</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" routerLink="/analytics" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled"> Workbench</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-append-to-body">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" (click)="navbar.dropdown=!navbar.dropdown" routerLink="/table" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" [attr.aria-expanded]="dropdown" aria-controlls="collapseExample">
                        Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div id = "collapseExample" [collapse]="!navbar.dropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item user">User</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying a multi level menus bar?

Comment: Yes, if I correctly understand your question, I am attempting to understand how to properly implement a Bootstrap 4 navbar w/ all it's options using Angular 4.  Look at the third example [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#nav) for pretty close to what I'm hoping for.  I want the ability to have a dropdown inside my navbar, which is clearly supported in the raw bootstrap 4, and possible to enable using jQuery, but I thought the point of ngx-bootstrap was to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: you can simply use bootstrap dopdown what error you are getting?

Comment: I cannot use the raw bootstrap dropdown without using ngx-bootstrap or ng-bootstrap because all the responsive components (dropdowns, the navbar collapse feature) in raw bootstrap use a javascript plugin (and likely depend on jQuery) rather than Angular for responsiveness.  For clarity and simplicity of code, I would like to use Angular to handle all responsiveness.